# Earth covered with water in the beginning?

Tags: theravada, reference-request, beginner

I have heard a monk saying, in the beginning of this kappa Earth was covered with water. And a god or a brahma, I dont remember exactly whom, had put a lotus seed into that water and there grown 5 flowers and they represented the 5 Buddhas (Kakusanda, Konagama, Kashyapa, Gautama, Meithri) in this kappa. But I could not find where in Tripitaka did the lord Buddha say that. So I highly apreciate if someone could help me to find any reference to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I recently discussed this in my blog. Here is a quote:

> The Buddha proceeds to tell Vasettha a cosmogony, a myth about the
>   origin of the world and life. The earth was originally entirely
>   covered by water, and everything was blinding darkness. There were no
>   sun, moon, stars, night, day, months, fortnights, years, seasons, or
>   gender. Interestingly, scientists believe that the earth was
>   originally a “waterworld,” almost entirely covered by water, about 2.5
>   billion years ago. The only life on earth at that time was sexless
>   algae and bacteria. After a very long period, a skin formed on the
>   surface of the water like the skin that forms over hot milk as it
>   cools. In this passage, the Buddha demonstrates that he understands
>   that the cause of the one world ocean at that time was the deep mantle
>   of the earth, which was 200 degrees hotter than it is now, and also
>   that it was cooling. As the deep mantle cooled, the continental crust
>   formed must have been as described in the sutta.
>
> During the waterworld era, any oxygen produced by photosynthesising
>   bacteria would have been quickly used up through reactions with
>   decaying organic matter in the oceans.
>
> When the newly emerged land eroded, it produced sediment that washed
>   into the oceans and buried the organic matter, preventing further
>   reactions with oxygen, the scientists believe. As a result, oxygen was
>   allowed to build up in the atmosphere and enable oxygen-breathing life
>   to evolve and flourish.
>
> The eroded sediment would also have fertilised the oceans with
>   phosphorous, an important nutrient for living things.[1]
>
> The Pali Canon calls this phosphorus “skin” rasa-pathavi (lit.
>   ‘earth-sap’). Interestingly in view of the subsequent reference to
>   luminance, phosphorus emits a faint glow when exposed to oxygen. It is
>   also an essential element of the human genetic material, DNA and RNA.

http://palisuttas.com/2015/04/26/aganna-sutta-dn-dn-27/

Comment: What about this bit from the OP -- "And a god or a brahma, I dont remember exactly whom, had put a lotus seed into that water and there grown 5 flowers and they represented the 5 Buddhas (Kakusanda, Konagama, Kashyapa, Gautama, Meithri) in this kappa" -- do you see that in the Aggañña Sutta, if not do you know where that might come from?